# How To compare A value from Android Chronometer while running

Tags: android, timer, long-press, chronometer

I have a chronometer started counting in seconds in a `LongPress` on an `ImageView`. I want to show a message in a `TextView` if the Chronometer is equal to 10 seconds while running.

This is my code :

```
private View.OnLongClickListener speakHoldListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View pView) {
      // Do something when your hold starts here.
      VibratMV();
      playsounde();
      StartAnimation();
      txtscanstat.setText(R.string.scanningstat);
      txtsavedstat.setText("");
      chrono.setText("");
      chrono.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      txtscanstat.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
      txtscanstat.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#434a54"));
      chrono.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#434a54"));
      chrono.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out));
      savebtn.setText(R.string.save_btn);
      savebtn.setEnabled(true);
      isScannerPressed = true;

      chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer cArg) {
              long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - cArg.getBase();
              int h   = (int)(time /3600000);
              int m = (int)(time - h*3600000)/60000;
              int s= (int)(time - h*3600000- m*60000)/1000 ;

              String ss = s < 10 ? "0"+s: s+"";


              chrono.setText(ss);

              if(chrono.getText().toString().equals(10)){
               txtscanstat.setText("You can");
              }
          }
      });
      chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
      chrono.start();

      return true;
  }
  };
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. You might want to take a look at [ask] and [mcve] - as it stands you could improve your chances of getting an answer by adding what issues/errors/confusion you're having with your current attempt.

Comment: Thank you jeff , i will take a look now